# How to change default windows (or dialogs) start position?

Tags: windows

After connecting a projector on my computer, screen resolution has changed accordingly to video output (from 1920x1080 to 1024x768). But that's not really a problem.

The problem is, now -- at high screen res --, when a window or a common dialog is opened, it is located at the top left corner of my screen. I guess this is due to last window size and position at low screen resolution.

How can I reset default windows start position (to be centered)?

Comment: I'm sure I've seen options to reset dialog positions in a couple of tweak tools, but my google-fu is failing me.. time to brute force it and write an autohotkey script? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information is stored in the registry in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags`. Just delete this key to unset previously saved windows/dialogs position.